# Laravel: Why is count() returning one less

Tags: laravel

Why are there 5 items in the array and count() outputs 4?

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $task = Task::findOrFail($id);

        dd($task->toArray(), $task->count());

        return view('pages.show')->with('task', $task);
    }
```

Outputs:

```
array:5 [▼
  "id" => 1
  "title" => "first"
  "description" => "description for first"
  "created_at" => "2016-10-09 19:34:04"
  "updated_at" => "2016-10-09 19:34:04"
]

4
```

The array clearly shows 5 items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `$task->count()` will return how many `Tasks` you have on your `tasks` table (by doing a count query to database), not how many columns you have.

Try using: `count($taks->toArray())`. It will return 5.